# Question about the meaning of the words "would" & "meet a stranger" & "grow old laughing"

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, idioms

> My friends would say that I never meet a stranger and I have fun where ever I go. Life is too short to not love what you are doing.  I want to find my best friend that I can share my life with and grow old laughing together!

1. When she says **my friends would say**, is this talking about the past — it was her friends' habit to say — or is this just use of the word **would** to show that someone is expressing their opinion like "I would say" or something like that?
2. When saying **grow old laughing** and **meet a stranger**, are these idioms?

Answer (score 4):

1. It is expressing a prediction/opinion, but with a lot of confidence/strong likelihood:  She is confident that if the subject came up, her friends would say that about her.  (Maybe because they have already said that about her, but not necessarily.)
2. "Never meet a stranger" is an idiom meaning you never consider a new person a stranger, you always find something to share.  "Grow old together" is a frequently-used idiom for what you hope to do with a life partner.  Here "laughing" is added to show what kind of life partner she is looking for.